# Wordpress Api not up to date

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm working on a project using WP's API along with VueJs + Nuxt for the front-end. Everything seemed to be working just fine, but since yesterday not all of my changes are fetched by the API.

It's really weird because, in the WP admin my changes are displayed as normal, but when looking at the response using postman, I can only see what was on my site prior to my changes, or only a few recent changes that don't even appear on the final render.

I am not using any type of extensions for cache as of now, but I've tried several extensions to empty it anyway, even if all of them signaled me that nothing is in the cache.

Could it be that the API got somehow "stuck" at some point and now no update is ever taken into account? Then is there anyway to "reset" this and force it to update?

Comment: I've never seen this type of hard api cache, there is no caching in WP by itself. try disabling as much as plugins as possible to see if those cause interference. Maybe the webserver adds some kind of caching?

Comment: Could you check API response header to see if any header could give us clue about a particular cache? Also, do you have the same results using Postman to call your API?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I am using Gandi to host my site and I had no idea thye used Varnish as a caching solution. Disabled it and everything went back to normal. Thanks for your answers!